# Tornado: get log_message of HTTPError for logging during on_finish of request handlers?

Tags: python, logging, tornado

I want to do some custom logging with Tornado.

When I throw a tornado.web.HTTPError with an error message, is there a way for me to retrieve the message for my request handler's on_finish() method? If not, how can I log it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to override RequestHandler's [`write_error`](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write_error) method:

```
RequestHandler.write_error(status_code, **kwargs)
```

You can process the exception there: log it or show custom page. The details of exception are kept in `kwargs["exc_info"]`.